# How to write array into plist?

Tags: objective-c

I have plist structure defined in resources folder. I want to write array into that plist programmatically. How i'll do that ?? .. I went through many post on stackOverflow and on other, but didn't find helpful. Plz help

Comment: You can not write in resource folder.

Comment: will i have to define structure programmatically?  In that case how will do ?

Answer (score 0):

The `-descriptionWithLocale:indent:` method of `NSArray` returns a string formatted as a property list.

Read up on property lists here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPropertyLists/CFPropertyLists.html